# returning 404 if not found really best option web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm putting my first web api solution together and have a query.

I have a Get() which I want to return a list of objects.

Currently if none are found I return a 404.

However in firebug etc I get the "1" that makes things look like they are "erroring" which isn't really the case.

Is this the best way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

As described on [Apigee's Web Api Design](http://apigee.com/about/resources/ebooks/web-api-design) you should try to keep the status code set small, like:

Start by using the following 3 codes. If you need more, add them. But you shouldn't need to go beyond 8.

- 200 - OK
- 400 - Bad Request
- 500 - Internal Server Error

If you're not comfortable reducing all your error conditions to these 3, try picking among these additional 5:

- 201 - Created
- 304 - Not Modified
- 404 – Not Found
- 401 - Unauthorized
- 403 - Forbidden

I like to always return 200 when an operation is successfully performed, even if no data is found.